# Prove that the length of the curve $y=f(x)$ is given by $\int_a^b \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

I'm trying to prove that the length of a curve of equation $y=f(x)$ is given by $$\ell=\int_a^b \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}dx$$
without using line integral (an using Riemann sum). So I consider only the case where $a=0$ and $b=1$. So I consider a regular partition $$\Pi:0<\frac{1}{n}<\frac{2}{n}<...<1.$$
Then, using a simple draw, I can make the approximation that for $n$ big enough, $$\ell\approx \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}+\left(f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)-f\left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right)\right)^2}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)-f\left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^2}.$$

Now, if $n$ is big enough, then $$\frac{f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)-f\left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}\approx -f'\left(\frac{k}{n}\right),$$
and thus,
$$\ell=\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)-f\left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^2}\approx\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{1+f'\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2}=\int_0^1\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}\mathrm d x.$$

**My question : How can I do it rigorously ?**

In other words, how can I get $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)-f\left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^2}=\int_0^1\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}\mathrm d x.$$

Comment: The result is obvious by mean value theorem and definition of Riemann integral. You need to assume the integrability of $f'^{2}$.

Comment: isn't this the definition of length of curve?

Comment: The point here is that you have two approximations at the same time: the integral as a Riemann sum (and this causes no problem, because the in tegral is defined through the limit of Riemann sums) and the summand itself, which is an approximation of the integrand. In fact, you deal in the sums with the approximation of the derivative. As pointed out in the comments by  Paramanand Singh, it is appropriate to use the mean value theorem, so the incremental ratio in the summands is actually the value of the first derivative in a point inseide the corresponding interval.

Comment: @madmatician: The length of a continuous curve is defined as the supremum of length of polygonal arcs made by a finite number points lying on the curve provided the supremum exists. The arc-length exists if and only if the function representing the curve is of bounded variation. See "Length of a Curve" in my blog post http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2012/07/functions-of-bounded-variation-part-2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that $f'^{2}$ is Riemann integrable on $[0, 1]$ which implies that $g(x) = \sqrt{1 + \{f'(x)\}^{2}}$ is Riemann integrable on $[0, 1]$ and hence by definition of Riemann integral as a limit of a sum we have $$\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1 + \{f'(x)\}^{2}}\,dx = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\sqrt{1 + \left\{f'(t_{k})\right\}^{2}}\tag{1}$$ where $t_{k}$ is any arbitrary point in $[(k - 1)/n, k/n]$. Now the approximation of arc-length (as mentioned in question) is given by $$F(n) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\sqrt{1 + \left(\dfrac{f\left(\dfrac{k}{n}\right) - f\left(\dfrac{k - 1}{n}\right)}{\dfrac{1}{n}}\right)^{2}}\tag{2}$$ By mean value theorem we have $$\dfrac{f\left(\dfrac{k}{n}\right) - f\left(\dfrac{k - 1}{n}\right)}{\dfrac{1}{n}} = f'(t_{k})\tag{3}$$ where $t_{k}$ is some point in $((k - 1)/n, k/n)$. The arc-length $l$ is given by $\lim_{n \to \infty}F(n)$ and using equations $(1)-(3)$ we see that $$l = \lim_{n \to \infty}F(n) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\sqrt{1 + \left\{f'(t_{k})\right\}^{2}} = \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1 + \{f'(x)\}^{2}}\,dx$$

Comment: My problem is that I just know that $\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{1+f'(x/k)^2}=\int_0^1\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}dx$, not $\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{1+f'(t_k)^2}$

Comment: @user330587: The definition of Riemann integral is the one which uses arbitrary $t_{k}$ rather than $k/n$. That one involving $k/n$ is the simplistic view championed by cheap textbooks (which means majority of calculus textbooks). It is better to update yourself with the right/correct knowledge. See my blog posts on Riemann integral at http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2012/07/the-riemann-integral-part-1.html